# Instance of 'Flight' has no 'id' member

Tags: python, django

[image]

Instance of 'Flight' has no 'id' member
It seems like I have no id non the above class but it was working on the video I had watched

Comment: Have you actually run the migrations yet? Also, please post and format code in your question in future, don't link to images of code.

Comment: yes i have already run migration

Comment: Is that an actual runtime error you’re getting, or just your IDE being obtuse?

Comment: I suspect the IDE. It's not flagging any of the other `self`s ... What is being used to check the code? Flake8? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install

`pip install pylint-django`

And in settings add this

```
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins",
    "pylint_django"
]
```

You can read about pylint-django plugin [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django)

Comment: where to add in setting ?

Comment: okay now that problem is solved but created other problems

Comment: What other problems?

Comment: all pylint errors like                                                                                                                                      pylint(redefined-outer-name)  ,  (missing module docstring) , (missing function docstring), (bad whitespace),  (missing-final-newline) , (missing class docstring)

Comment: I just want to get rid of redefined outer class and docstrings problem in class, module, and function

Comment: Try adding this in the settings too `--errors-only` in `python.linting.pylintArgs`.